# Passing arguments in assembly and print it out

Tags: assembly

I am trying to take the argument (which will *always* be a single digit) and convert it from a string to
an int, and print it out on screen.

When I run my program with

```
./test 3
```

I get a really large negative value...

This is what I have:

```
SECTION .data
str1: db "argument = %d",0,10

SECTION .text
global main
extern printf

 main:
    enter 0,0
    pusha

    mov eax, dword [ebp+12]   
    add eax, 4                
    mov bl,[eax]               ; put the one bit into bl

    sub ebx, '0'               ; subtract null terminating string to convert to int

    push ebx
    push str1
    call printf                ; print the string
    add esp, 8               

    popa
    leave
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xor ebx, ebx               ; Clear ebx to zero, so the following operation will not have random values in the higher part of ebx
mov bl,[eax]               ; put the one bit into bl
sub ebx, '0'               ; subtract null terminating string to convert to int
```

Comment: I added the line `xor ebx,ebx` but still does not give me the right answer

Comment: You don't mention which OS you are on. In Windows you would have to call 'GetCommandLine'. Why do you assume that it would be at [ebp+12]? Did you use a debugger to check if you really read the correct value? http://www.network54.com/Forum/632471/message/1307235592/Getting+command+line+arguments+using+the+Win32+API